# Adding variable to upcomming array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a  multi dimensional array with some values coming from a foreach, i need to insert this values into the array, but at this moment my result is this, not sure why:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => MySecure
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productTitle] => My New Product
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => My Second Company
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [productTitle] => Another Product
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [productTitle] => Away Product
        )

)
```

This is wrong, what i need is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => MySecure
            [productTitle] => My New Product
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => My Second Company
            [productTitle] => Another Product  
            [productTitle] => Away Product
        )  

)
```

So this is what i have done:

```
$companies[] = [
                    'title' => $getCompanie->getTitle()
               ];
```

Then inside products :

```
$companies[] = [
                        'productTitle' => $getProduct->getTitle(),
                   ];
```

so i assume im using the wrong array call, not sure about array_push?

Comment: Your second nested array isn't possible. Keys in an array have to be unique, you can't have two `productTitle` in the same array.

Comment: Maybe it should be an array: `'productTitle' => ['Another Product', 'Away Product']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add both keys in the same inner array, rather than pushing them separately.

Use nested loops to get all the products associated with a company in the same loop.

```
$companies = [];
foreach ($all_companies as $companie) {
    $products = [];
    foreach ($companie->getProducts() as $getProduct) {
        $products[] = $getProduct->getTitle());
    }
    $companies[] = [
        'title' => $companie->getTitle(),
        'productTitle' => $products
    ]
}
```

I've had to make up names for some of the things I assumed are in your code. You should be able to extrapolate from this to your actual design.

Comment: Im on a diferent loop so thats why i cant add this, i will get separates companies for every product.

Comment: How does it know which products go with which products? Maybe you shoiuld make it an associative array so you can add the products to the proper company.

Comment: Or you can use nested loops to get all the products with the current company.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$newArray= [
    'title' => array_map($yourArray,fn($ar)=>$ar['title']),
    'productTitle' => array_map($yourArray,fn($ar)=>$ar['productTitle'])
];
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.